# Installing CruiseControl.Net 1.8 on OS X Lion breaks immediately because of NAnt

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

I am trying to install CruiseControl.Net v1.8 on OS X Lion. I have the latest release of mono installed (2.10.9). I run:

```
sh build-all.sh
```

The build starts but immediately fails with the following error:

> *BUILD FAILED*
>
> *`../ccnet.build(47,3)`:*
>
> *Target framework could not be changed. `mono-4.0` is not a valid framework identifier. Valid values are: `mono-2.0`, `moonlight-2.0`, `mono-1.0`, `mono-3.5`.*
>
> *Total time: 0.1 seconds.*

I have not previously installed NAnt or CruiseControl.Net on this machine. I heard online that supposedly the newest version of NAnt does not have this problem, so I downloaded the latest version and replaced everything in CruiseControl.Net's Tools/NAnt folder with the contents of the newly downloaded NAnt's bin folder. After I did that and ran the build again I received the following error:

> *Williams-MacBook:CruiseControl.NET-1.8.0.0.source williamkeen [(no branch)] $ `sh build.sh`*
>   *Buildfile: `file:///Users/williamkeen/Downloads/CruiseControl.NET-1.8.0.0.source/ccnet.build`*
>   *Target framework: Mono 2.0 Profile*
>   *Target(s) specified:*
>
> *[property] Target framework changed to "Mono 4.0 Profile".*
>
> *BUILD FAILED*
>
> *Target '' does not exist in this project.*
>
> *Total time: 0.2 seconds.*

Looking online some more I found that this was supposedly a guaranteed fix with CC.Net 1.6. Any help would be appreciated. I'm at the end of the road here, I have no idea what to try next.

Comment: You might have better luck with CC.NET 1.6, not the newer releases, there wasn't much usage of CC.NET + Mono by the project developers after that release.

'Target framework changed' comes from NAnt, it does not mean you Mono actually supports this profile. But it should. All in all, if you want the 'current' CCNET to build on Mono, best to follow your bug report: http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/issues/170

This is something I'm interested in fixing personally, but my work will need to wait until autumn.

Comment: I scheduled to fix the issue for the next CCNet version 1.9